# MVC code, throwing error on index.cstml, non-static field error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this `index.cshtml` code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Desa.Models.Person>

<p>Person List Page</p>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@Person.name</td>
            <td>@Person.email</td>
            <td>@Person.phone  </td>
            <td>@Person.address</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

And the `Person` model:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Desa.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

On the `Index.cshtml` part it's throwing an error saying:

> *CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property **'Person.name'** Desa
>
> C:\Users\qendr\source\repos\Desa\Desa\Views\Person\Index.cshtml 15
>
> Active*

I'm not quite sure what might be the issue, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `foreach` to iterate the `IEnumerable<Desa.Models.Person>` collection. Therefore it is necessary to reference to the collection item like below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@item.name</td>
    <td>@item.email</td>
    <td>@item.phone  </td>
    <td>@item.address</td>
</tr>
}
```

For details see the Microsoft documentation: [Strongly typed views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0#strongly-typed-views)

Comment: oh my bad! It worked, thank you for checking!